# Titlesec heading styling only works on chapter, not sections or subsections

Tags: fonts, sectioning, titlesec

I am trying to use the titlesec package in order to have custom heading styles. I have defined the style I want for chapters, sections, and subsections, but only the chapter styling works.

This is my code, including my custom font profiles:

```
% Custom fonts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % For unicode characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % For unicode characters
\usepackage{fontspec} % For imported font files
\setmainfont{NotoSerif-Regular.ttf} % Main font
\newfontfamily{\ipa}{NotoSerif-Regular.ttf} % IPA font
\newfontfamily{\textbf}{NotoSerif-Bold.ttf} % Bold font
\newfontfamily{\textit}{NotoSerif-Italic.ttf} % Italic font
\newfontfamily{\textsansbf}{NotoSans-Bold.ttf} % Sans bold font
\newfontfamily{\textsans}{NotoSans-Regular.ttf} % Sans font
\newfontfamily{\textsansit}{NotoSans-Italic.ttf} % Sans italic font

% Heading styling
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Chapter styling
\titleformat{\chapter} % Command
  {\textsansbf\Huge} % Format
  {} % Label
  {0pt} % sep
  {} % Before

% Section styling
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\filcenter\textsansit\huge}
  {} % Label
  {.5em} % Sep
  {} % Before

% Subsection styling
\titleformat{name=\subsection,numberless}
  {\textsansit\Large}
  {} % Label
  {.5em} % Sep
  {} % Before

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Introduction}
Introductory text.

\section{Section}
Section text.

\subsection{Subsection}
Subsection text.

\end{document}
```

And this is what it outputs:
[image]

I am using XeLaTeX compiler.

If you need me to elaborate on anything or prvide more details/code, just ask.

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: `numberless` is not about omitting section numbers, but about printing the numberless section headers. You can add `\subsection*{Something}` to see the difference.

Comment: Ah I see it has applied the heading style! Is there any way to have the numbers beside the section as well as the custom section style?

Comment: use `\titleformat` without the `numberless` key and specify the label.

Comment: How do I specify the label?

Comment: `\thesection` or something (as the third argument).

Comment: It doesn’t seem to work but it doesn’t matter. Thank you for your help with the applying the heading styles?

Comment: Redefining `\textbf` is not the best idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `numberless` option is for defining a separate format when the section is not numbered.

If you want no number, it's better to set `secnumdepth`.

Note that `inputenc` and `fontenc` should not be used with XeLaTeX. Also, fonts should be defined in a different way.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec} % For imported font files
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Custom fonts

\setmainfont{NotoSerif}[
%  Extension = .ttf,
  Extension = .otf,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
]
\setsansfont{NotoSans}[
%  Extension = .ttf,
  Extension = .otf,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
]

% Heading styling

% Chapter styling
\titleformat{\chapter} % Command
  {\sffamily\bfseries\Huge} % Format
  {\thechapter} % Label
  {1ex} % sep
  {} % Title

% Section styling
\titleformat{\section}
  {\filcenter\sffamily\itshape\huge}
  {\thesection} % Label
  {0.5em} % Sep
  {} % Title

% Subsection styling
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\sffamily\itshape\Large}
  {\thesubsection} % Label
  {0.5em} % Sep
  {} % Before

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2} % no numbering

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

\chapter{Introduction}
Introductory text.

\section{Section}
Section text.

\subsection{Subsection}
Subsection text.

\end{document}
```

I have the OTF version of the Noto fonts, so I used a different extension; just choose the one that suits you.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Should `inputenc` and `fontenc` not be used as XeLaTeX can compile ‘special’ characters as they’re inputed. Will it cause issues if `inputenc` and `fontenc` are not removed from the preamble?                                   Edit: I would like the section and subsection to be numbered. I have removed the ‘numberless’ command and they show up in the ToC, but now the section, subsection etc. are not numbered.

Comment: @Tomsk `inputenc` is actually ignored and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` would be overridden. In certain cases `fontenc` can be useful also with XeLaTeX, but not with normal documents.

Comment: Ah okay. Do you happen to know why I can no longer have section numbers (such as 1.1 1.1.1 etc.)?

Comment: @Tomsk Remove the setting to `secnumdepth`.

Comment: That only seems to number the chapter, not the section, subsection etc.

Comment: @Tomsk You're not using `\section*` or `\subsection*`, are you?

Comment: No I’ve figured it all out now and it’s how I wanted. Thank you very much for all your help!